# close titanium application

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

while starting the application, if it cannot connect to the server then I want to close the application. Please note that I have not opened any window or tabgroup. How can I close the application? In case it is not possible to close the application directly, please let me know if I can close the application by using titanium-android-module.

P.S.: making an app for android using Titanium.

Comment: You want to exit the application?

Comment: Yes, close the application.. basically, at startup, application tries to connect to server. If it cannot connect to server, i want to close the application.

Comment: I think you have to open the app and in app.js file use this solution: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/83911/titaniumappexit-for-android